# force:hasRecordId interface doesn't provide recordId from “new” button override

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have two custom objects (let's call them House and Resident).

The House record page has a related list containing all related residents.

I also have two lightning components (ResidentDetails and NewResident).

NewResident is called from two places, in ResidentDetails on a different record page. As well as from the "new" button override for Resident.

NewResident implements force:hasRecordId and lightning:actionOverride (see below).

However, as it is launched in a different context (the new resident page, like so: blah.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Resident__c/new).

My problem is, the recordId attribute doesn't contain the House record Id.

`component.get("v.recordId")` results in `undefined` in `doInit`.

Relevant code samples:

*NewResident.cmp*

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId" controller="ResidentDetailsController" access="global">
    <!--Handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <p>{!v.recordId}</p> <!--empty-->
    
    <!--A bunch of other irrelevant stuff-->
</aura:component>
```

*NewResidentController.js*

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId")); //logs `undefined`
    },
})
```

This does work if I call the component from the ResidentDetails component, but doesn't when overriding the new resident button.

My question is: is there a way to retrieve the recordId from the previous context?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this isn't yet possible with Salesforce. The Salesforce support engineer I spoke to wasn't aware of any plans to implement the feature anytime soon.

In my specific scenario, I will have to re-implement the "related list" functionality in an aura component, which then calls the "new" component.